# How to sort multiple vectors but using only the first element

Tags: sorting, vector

I have a map with the number of words in a vector as the key and the vector with the strings as the value. 
I have a bunch of string vectors and the vectors are individually sorted alphabetically but only from [1] to end of vector. The first element is used as a head node in another function so I don't want that sorted.

However when outputting the vectors after the inital sort I want to output them in alphabetical order. So how would I sort my vectors but only using the first element ? [0]

ex:

```
 vector<string> v1;
 v1.push_back("d"); 
 v1.push_back("b");
 v1.push_back("c");

 vector<string> v2;
 v2.push_back("a"); 
 v2.push_back("e");
 v2.push_back("f");

 multimap<int, vector<string>> mmap;
 mymap.insert(make_pair(v1.size(), v1));
 mymap.insert(make_pair(v2.size(), v2));
```

Now I want my multimap to be sorted using the key values obviously. 
But then I want to have the different entries with the same key's vectors sorted alphabetically only by the first element in the vectors.

How would I do this?